# FullCalendar disable select day if is not allowed in selectAllow callback

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

In the FullCalendar plugin, I need allow selection of days until a day or between dates. I put an example to explain better.

https://codepen.io/stefanmalex/pen/Jjjjgmp

I have an array with disallowed days:

```
var disallowedDays = ['2019-10-17', '2019-10-23', '2019-10-26']
```

I added the 'selectAllow' callback:

```
selectAllow: function (selectInfo) {
  if (disallowedDays.includes(selectInfo.startStr)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

This works perfectly if you select day per day, allows selection of all days less disallowed days in array.

PROBLEM: When you select multiple days, it allows select disallowed days. (Example: select from '2019-10-15' to '2019-10-26').

What I need, example:
If the selection starts on '2019-10-11', it has to allows you to select until '2019-10-16' because next day ('2019-10-17') is disallowed.

I let the example on codepen. https://codepen.io/stefanmalex/pen/Jjjjgmp

Comment: Hi, Please note that in the selectAllow, you used "selectInfo.startStr", startStr is present in select callback, NOT in selectAllow, Please check the parameters https://fullcalendar.io/docs/selectAllow

Comment: @KhurramIshaque `startStr is present in select callback, in selectAllow` ...I assume you mean "**not** present in selectAllow"? :-)

Comment: So, basically that piece of code is not working in selectAllow

Comment: @KhurramIshaque "always return true" ...no it will cause a script error due to an undefined variable :-)

Comment: hehe.. Thanks ADyson for corrections

Comment: @KhurramIshaque although strangely, when I tested it, it doesn't cause an error. It seems that `startStr` (and `endStr` are actually present in the `selectInfo` provided to `selectAllow` even though it's not documented. Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYYEBqL . So actually it must be OP's program logic which is faulty.

Comment: Tank you all guys. Sorry for my mistake, you are true, I was only checking the `startStr`... I changed the logic to check that `end.getTime()` is lower than next allowed date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADyson has recognized it correctly.
The program logic needs to be changed.
In the `selectAllow` you were checking the array with startStr, so basically it will be checking with start date of selection only, not the whole selection.
So, if you tried to select 14 oct to 18 oct, you needed to check / compare the disallowed dates with in this range.
So, it is needed to loop through the disallowedDays array to check each date within the tried selection, like the following loop:

```
for(var i=0;i<disallowedDays.length;i++)   {
    var dd = new Date(disallowedDays[i]);
    if(dd.getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && dd.getTime() <= endDate.getTime()){
        return true;
    }
  }
```

Following this logic, [check here](https://codepen.io/khurramishaque/pen/dyyPyVX) the solution you might be expecting

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments and solution. I add your solution to my codepen too. thx

Comment: So, basically the solution worked fine for you ? If so, please mark and accept the answer, Thank you :)