# FullCalendar for bookings, selectable drag/click

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

Is it FullCalendar able to do something like the airbnb.com calendar for booking homes? Select dates between range of available days by clicking (not dragging)?

I have created a calendar that let you select dates by dragging from start to end, `selectable: true` and `selectMinDistance: 2`.

Example: https://codepen.io/khurramishaque/pen/dyyPyVX (from: [FullCalendar disable select day if is not allowed in selectAllow callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58266675/fullcalendar-disable-select-day-if-is-not-allowed-in-selectallow-callback))

Motivation: switch drag by click, render/select available days

My question is: can I use `dayRender` callback again when `dateClick` is fired?

Comment: dateClick doesn't trigger dayRender, no. dayRender is triggered when the view is re-drawn. Why do you care if it's click vs drag, though? You din't explain what advantage you are hoping to get from that.

Comment: However you could achieve the selection fairly simply - handle dateClick, as you suggested. That gives you access to the HTML element of the clicked day, so you can easily change its colour to mark it as selected (that was your motivation for wanting dayRender, I assume). You can then maintain your own array (outside of fullCalendar) containing a list of all the days clicked on by the user.

Comment: You could do the same still using the "select" functionality as well though, if you need to be able to select specific times (although keeping the selection coloured might  be trickier, I think. This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29212500/5947043 proposes a way to handle that by creating temporary event sources to cover the selected areas (code is for an older version of the calendar, but the concept still works)

Comment: P.S  there seems to be an open issue about adding built-in support for multiple selections. Maybe you'd want to add your vote to it: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4387

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no built-in support for this feature. However you could fairly easily implement this yourself.

In a short list:

1. Disable selectable, since it's not going to help you here
2. Bind to `dateClick` [event](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/dateClick) and save the start date that is returned
3. In the same function handling the `dateClick` event, if you have a start date saved, get the end date and manually create the event using `addEvent` [function](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent)

That's if you want to create an event. But you could do whatever else you want with this data and just call `render` on the calendar object.

For example:

```
var startDate = false;
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    selectable: false,
    dateClick: function (info) {
        if (startDate !== false) { // startDate has been selected, create event
            this.addEvent({
                title: "An event title",
                start: startDate,
                end: info.date
            });
            startDate = false;
        } else { // No start date, set it
            startDate = info.date;
        }
    }
});
```

*Note: I haven't tested the code above. You may need to initialize `calendar` first and then bind the dateClick event and replace `this` with `calendar`*